# What's the best way for calling another reducer from inside a reducer in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Basically I have two slices, `app2Fa` and `webAuthnSettingsSlice` , I need that whenever the `setApp2FA` reducer is dispatched with a `false` value, the `isEnabled` value in `webAuthnSettingsSlice` is also set to false :

app2FA

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const app2FASlice = createSlice({
    name: 'app2FA',
    initialState: false,
    reducers: {
        setApp2FA: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
            return action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export const { setApp2FA } = app2FASlice.actions;
export const app2FAReducer = app2FASlice.reducer;
export const selectApp2FA = (state: { app2fa: boolean }) => state.app2fa;
```

webAuthnSettingsSlice

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export interface WebAuthnSettingsState {
    isEnabled: boolean;
}

const initialState: WebAuthnSettingsState = {
    isEnabled: false,

};

const webAuthnSettingsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'webauthn',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        setEnabled: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
            return { ...state, isEnabled: action.payload };
        },
    },
});

export const { setEnabled, add2FAMethod, delete2FAMethod, setDefault } =
    webAuthnSettingsSlice.actions;
export const webAuthnReducer = webAuthnSettingsSlice.reducer;
export const selectWebAuthnSettings = (state: {
    webauthn: WebAuthnSettingsState;
}) => state.webauthn;
```